# Crystal oscillators vs LC circuits

Tags: oscillator, clock, crystal

I have 3 questions about crystal oscillators, their relation with an RF coil and their usage in electric circuits.

[image]

1. This image of a crystal oscillator is all over google and youtube, but no one actually shows what it does. When you apply a voltage and briefly disconnect it, does the disk wobble in place or hit each other, or both? Does this action work like an on/off switch and connect/disconnect the two discs OR do wobbling discs produce alternating electricity? If the latter, then where does this electricity come from, does the crystal create it out of thin air? I wish there was a slow motion video of what it actually does.
2. I wanted to compare crystals with the combination of a RF coil and a capacitor in an LC circuit. Does the crystal oscillator pretty much do the same thing and create alternating current in the circuit?
3. My last question is about the crystal's frequency and how it is used in electric circuits. A computer clock consists of a high voltage and a low voltage (i.e 5V and 0V,) but the crystal oscillator is alternating current with a sine graph correct? It does't just go from 1 to 0 in an instant? It works like an analogue signal. If so then how id its current converted to 0V/5V or a square graph?

Comment: The image you link to shows a crystal. A crystal oscillator is a circuit that uses this crystal and produces a sustained oscillating output. It needs at least a power source and a gain device (transistor or op-amp, for example) in addition to the crystal.

Comment: *produces a sustained oscillating output* how?! that's what no one really shows in a video. You hookup the two sides to power then what happens?

Comment: Please read this old question: [How does a Crystal work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/117624/6334) and edit your new question to ask specifically about what you still need help with after reading it.

Comment: The device you show is not an a oscillator. It is a crystal. The crystal is only one component in the oscillator circuit. You cannot just hook it up to power and get an oscillating output.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. So you apply power to it in a pattern which makes those discs oscillate and this oscillation produces alternating current for a period of time? questions 2 and 3 still remain.

Comment: you use the crystal as a filter in an oscillator circuit to make sure it oscillates at the frequency you want it to. The crystal doesn't produce an alternating current. The circuit as a whole does.

Comment: Think at a diapason: it does not vibrate by itself but, if you excite (pulse) it, it will vibrate at a specific frequency (440 Hz?) and then decay slowly . If you want a continuous vibration you have to hit the diapason continually, in phase with its own frequency. A crystal resembles, electrically, a diapason, I think. Giving a DC current to a crystal is the same as applying a still force to a diapason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you apply a voltage and briefly disconnect it, does the disk wobble in place or hit each other, or both? does this action work like an on/off switch and connect/disconnect the two discs OR do wobbling discs produce alternating electricity?

The disk doesn't so much wobble as it expands and contracts due to its piezoelectric nature. The Wikipedia article on [crystal oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator) has an illustration showing the various modes a crystal might vibrate in. Likely these vibrations are too small to be seen with the naked eye.

> if the latter then where does this electricity come from, does the crystal create it out of thin air?

The crystal is piezoelectric so in principle you could apply a mechanical force to it and it would produce a small voltage in response.

Practically, we build the crystal into an oscillator circuit and provide power to it with a battery or power supply, and this is what provides the energy to vibrate the crystal and to produce the oscillator's output signal. In this case, any piezoelectric response to mechanical stimulus (called "microphonics") is undesirable as it produces noise in the oscillator output.

> I wanted to compare crystals with the combination of a RF coil and a Capacitor in an LC circuit. Does the crystal oscillator pretty much do the same thing ..

Yes, electrically, the crystal behaves very much like an inductor and capacitor in series.

Its advantage is that it has a higher "Q" factor than can be realized with practical discrete inductors and capacitors, so it provides a sharper resonant peak than an LC circuit can.

> and create alternating current in the circuit?

No, this is not what a crystal does and it is not what an inductor-capacitor filter circuit does.

To use a crystal (or LC filter) to produce an alternating current, you must build an oscillator circuit around the resonant element.

There are many such circuits, which apply the resonant element in different ways. One of the simplest conceptually is the [Pierce oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator).

> A computer clock consists of a high voltage and a low voltage (i.e 5V and 0V). But the crystal oscillator is alternating current with a sine graph correct? it does't just go from 1 to 0 in an instant? it works like an analogue signal. If so then how does its current get converted to 0V/5V or a square graph?

You can use a comparator or a high gain digital buffer circuit to convert a sinusoidal signal to a digital square wave.

In the case of the Pierce oscillator referenced above, since the gain element is actually a digital inverter, the output is digital (square wave rather than sine wave) and no conversion is required.

Comment: *No, this is not what a crystal does and it is not what an inductor-capacitor filter circuit does.* Sorry but according to this video, and many articles online, does it not create an alternating current in wire? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_y_3_3V-so

Comment: @Dan, what they didn't mention in the video (at least the first minute or so that I watched) is that for the oscillation they're describing to happen, something has to introduce energy into the system. Neither the capacitor nor the inductor can create energy. They only store it. So to make a practical oscillator with an LC tuning element, you need some other components to actually provide the energy.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought that was implied. Yes assume there is a battery on the line, in which case both the crystal and the LC circuit would create an alternating current like the video?

Comment: Look at time = 2:50 in that video.  It tells you the oscillations are damped, then the video -- rather unhelpfully -- ends.  To make _sustained oscillation_, there needs to be a circuit that uses the crystal as a control element, but continually feeds energy back into it.  That's the _oscillator_ part.

Comment: So crystal is like the RF coil in LC. There needs to be another part like the capacitor to restart the oscillation process correct? but what I'm also trying to confirm is, the crystal and the LC both create an alternating current in the wire?

Comment: @Dan, No a capacitor will not produce energy, only store it. You need an active element like a transistor or op-amp to take power from the power supply and provide it to the resonant element. Neither the crystal nor the LC filter "create" an alternating current without a source of energy. Did you read the Wikipedia pages I provided links to?

Comment: Yes, sorry maybe i'm having a hard time getting my thought across. Assume we have a proper LC circuit with power, similar to the YouTube video, this circuit will have alternating current through it right? Now same will hold if certain crystal oscillators are used instead?

Comment: @Dan, yes, an oscillator (the whole circuit) produces an AC signal. An oscillator can be designed with either an LC filter or a crystal as the frequency-determining element. Did you read the Wikipedia pages I provided links to?

Comment: Yes I went over the linked pages, thanks for confirming, and depending on the type of crystal oscillator used, we might need a *comparator* to make the signal digital from analogue as you have mentioned. Just to confirm one more thing, the **clock** generated by them on digital machines will be a frequency of high voltage and low voltage right? not high voltage and power cut (i.e floating current).

Comment: @Dan, a digital clock will switch between high and low voltage.

Comment: @Dan, you should know that in oscillator circuits a crystal can be used in two different ways (depending on the oscillator type): (1) It can be used as a high-Q series resonant block (with zero phase shift at w=wo) or (2) as a high-Q inductor in conjunction with associated resistors and capacitors. In the latter case, it forms a 3rd-0rder lowpass or  highpass  with a 180deg phase shift (at w=wo). For example, this is the case in the mentioned Pierce oscillator. It is an inverting loop and zero phase shift at w=wo would not allow oscillations.

Answer (score 1):

Neither a picture nor a normal video will show what the resonator does, because its mechanical vibrations are tiny. You don’t see it doing anything at all. The power levels involved are microwatts. A crystal resonator attached to a working oscillator circuit appears just as “dead” as if the battery ran out.

As for how can a crystal resonator work: by transduction. The transducer action couples the mechanical and electrical domains. In fact, the main reason we use mechanical resonators is that it’s not feasible to produce equivalently good lumped electrical components. So instead, we couple the electrical voltage to mechanical strain, and can use the mechanical system to implement an equivalent LC tank that would be impossible to make as electrical coil and capacitor. But we can describe the mechanical resonator’s behavior, as seen from electrical domain, very accurately by using the idealized components that you find in circuit modeling.

Same thing happens with speakers. You can couple a speaker to an acoustic resonator, use it as a transducer, and have that resonator put into an electrical oscillator circuit. Voilà, an electro-acoustic oscillator! And by the way, yes, you could replace the speaker+resonator with a purely electrical model.

Same happens with electrical circuits driving heaters and heat propagating through solids, etc. You can replace electrical circuits with physical equivalents in other domains. Sometimes those other domains make the problem much easier. For example the high-q resonators can often be mechanical rather than electrical. If you need to delay electrical signals, using a mechanical transmission line as a delay element for “low” frequency signals is much cheaper and easier than using an equivalent electrical transmission line, even one built from lots of lumped elements.

From electrical circuit’s perspective, the crystal resonator appears exactly like a very efficient high Q electrical tank circuit would look. The reason that this “appearance” works is by coupling mechanical and electrical domains via transduction that uses some effect that links the domains. E.g. crystal resonators use piezoelectric effect, electroacoustic resonators and delay lines may use Faraday forces (say a speaker coil), magnetostriction is used in nickel actuators in wire memories (a real thing, used in some electronic calculators from the early 70s!), and piezoelectricity is used in those annoying buzzers, but also in sonography heads, etc.